# print pdf with copies

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

We print pdf file with c#. Works fine, but is there any chance to set the number of copies
somewhere? I don't want a loop.

```
ProcessStartInfo infoPrintPdf = new ProcessStartInfo();
infoPrintPdf.FileName = filename;
// The printer name is hardcoded here, but normally I get this from a combobox with all printers
string printerName = druckerS;
string driverName = "printqueue.inf";
string portName = "192.168.0.119";
infoPrintPdf.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
infoPrintPdf.Arguments = string.Format("/t {0} \"{1}\" \"{2}\" \"{3}\"",
    filename, printerName, driverName, portName);
infoPrintPdf.CreateNoWindow = true;
infoPrintPdf.UseShellExecute = false;
infoPrintPdf.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
Process printPdf = new Process();
printPdf.StartInfo = infoPrintPdf;
printPdf.Start();

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

if (!printPdf.CloseMainWindow())              // CloseMainWindow never seems to succeed
    printPdf.Kill(); printPdf.WaitForExit();  // Kill AcroRd32.exe

printPdf.Close();  // Close the process and release resources
```

Comment: Looks like you can't : https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=command+line+adobe+acrobat+print, at least not with the Acrobat Reader.

Answer (score 0):

Most command line PDF printers (Acrobat, Foxit etc) support only 1 copy unless you use a loop.   After much searching the best I have found that is free (non-commercial usage) is PDF Studio from Bullzip:

```
"pathto\PdfStudio.exe" "MyPDF.pdf" /copies 3 /printer "My Printer"
```